# SQL Server BULK INSERT of Over 1 Million rows - Need Performance Improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, bulkinsert

I have been tasked with developing a method for importing text files with 1 million or more rows into a table. Each row within the table is 856 Bytes, split into approximately 150 "columns" of data. I am using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. The activity related to the INSERTs is the only activity on the database. I have built a stored procedure that does the following:

```
GET LIST OF UNIMPORTED DATA FILES IN A SPECIFIC DIRECTORY
LOOP THROUGH LIST OF FILES
    BULK INSERT INDIVIDUAL FILE DATA INTO (DISK-BASED) TEMP TABLE
    LOOP THROUGH RECORD-LEVEL DATA IN TEMP TABLE
    PARSE/WRITE RECORD-LEVEL DATA TO DETAILRECORD TABLE
    IF ALL RECORDS FOR A GIVEN FILE ARE SUCCESSFULLY WRITTEN TO THE DETAIL RECORD TABLE
        THEN 
            MOVE FILE TO IMPORTED_FILES DIRECTORY
            WRITE SUCESS RECORD TO IMPORTLOG TABLE
        ELSE
            WRITE FAIL RECORD TO IMPORTLOG TABLE
            MOVE ON TO NEXT FILE
```

The BULK INSERT of the raw text file into the TEMP TABLE is fast enough, at less than 1 minute. However, I need to parse that raw data and put the data into its destination table. To be clear, that means, for example, that data from row location 1-10 should be written to  in the destination table, 11-13 should be written to  in the destination table, etc. I am doing this by using a WHILE loop instead of a CURSOR and looping through each of the 1 million rows, then passing the raw data as a parameter to another stored procedure that then parses the raw data and inserts into the destination table. I am parsing the raw data simply by using the SUBSTRING function, i.e. SUBSTRING(@rawdata,1,10).
And as I mentioned, there are approximately 150 fields within each row. Performance of the parsing/writing step is terrible, however. It's has taken 10 hours to import 170K rows.

There are no clustered indexes on the destination table. The Recovery Model is set to SIMPLE. I have "Instant File Initialization" enabled.

I am looking at possibly using SSIS, but 1) I suspect performance might not be much faster, and 2) troubleshooting seems more cumbersome in SSIS.

Looking for thoughts, brilliant ideas, and obvious suggestions I've overlooked.

EDIT (Added code inside WHILE loop):

```
WHILE @RecordCounter <= @FileRecordCount
BEGIN
    SELECT @Record = record FROM CDR.tempFile WHERE id = @RecordCounter                                 

    EXEC [CDR].[usp_ImportCDRData_Record] @pRecord = @Record, @pCarrier = @carrier, @pLogid = @ImportLogID

    SET @RecordCounter = @RecordCounter + 1
END

--Inside [CDR].[usp_ImportCDRData_Record] 

INSERT INTO dbo.DetailRecord
    ( 
    LOGID ,
    ACCOUNTNUMBER ,
    CORPID ,
    SERVICELOCATION ,
    NETWORKINDICATOR ,
    ...
    )
VALUES
    ( 
    @pLogID,
    SUBSTRING(@pRecord, 1,10), -- ACCOUNTNUMBER
    SUBSTRING(@pRecord, 11,8), -- CORPID
    SUBSTRING(@pRecord, 19,8), -- SERVICELOCATION
    SUBSTRING(@pRecord, 27,1), -- NETWORKINDICATOR
    ...
    )
```

Comment: This seems like a good fit for an ETL tool rather than trying to do it entirely in T-SQL. I've not used SSIS but it would be pretty trivial in Talend.

Comment: CLR is one possible solution to your complex splitting. Is there a reason you are doing the task in a loop?

Comment: Voted to be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What other options do I have aside from a loop when needing to parse 1 row at a time and insert into the destination table? And, CLR is not my area of expertise.

Comment: I think SSIS will be much faster because parsing in application code is much more efficient than in T-SQL.  I would expect SSIS can import 170K records in minutes (or seconds), not hours.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into SSIS, and the possibly Talend if SSIS doesn't perform well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a WHILE loop think about a set based solution where you don't have to treat every single row separately.

If you could share some more information what code is in the WHILE loop, we might be able to speed it up considerably. Even without using SSIS ;-)

At the moment I'd disagree there's a "need" to parse one row at a time...

Comment: I was able to reduce the import time down to 50 seconds for 1.3 million records in a text file by eliminating the loop. There really was no need for the WHILE Loop, as I just did the parsing/splitting of data at the "set" level. In other words, I now have only 1 INSERT statement in the [CDR].[usp_ImportCDRData_Record] that does the parsing/splitting on all records in the temp table and inserts them into the DetailRecord table. Thanks for getting me to look at the problem from a set-based approach.

Comment: 10hrs for 170k rows with a loop vs. 50sec for 1.3 million rows with a set based solution -> that's one of the best examples why a loop (regardless of CURSOR or WHILE) should be replaced with a set-based solution!